# Anti-PD1 in adjuvancy after resection of metastatic melanoma in Europe

Tags: cancer, melanoma, metastatic-cancer

I was wondering if it is possible to get anti-PD1 (nivo/pembro/...) treatment in an adjuvant setting after resection of metastatic melanoma. Even if that means paying the treatment.

As far as I know, anti-PD1 (pembro and nivo) are approved for advanced metastatic melanoma but they are not approved for adjuvancy.

I'd like to know whether it's possible for an oncologist (legally) to provide an anti-PD1 in an adjuvant setting for resected metastases in melanoma.

The case is in Spain if that helps.

Comment: This is an obviously important question to ask, due to the time-sensitive nature of metastatic melanoma treatment.  It is unlikely that a person with this very specific knowledge will be found here.  It isn't impossible.  But I would recommend asking other oncologists in your region or abroad, as it is less likely you will get the answer you seek here.